# Knockout why does my first form.submit work but not the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have three views which posts a JSON-object to backend to generate a PDF. The first in the hierarchy works, not the two others. The code is practically identical, and uses the same method to programmatically add a hidden input-field with the JSON-data.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what the problem is.

First i thought Knockout was creating the problem since the form-elements are added in a foreach-loop, in a AJAX-success-event, but every view is identical in this respect.

I've tried all variations of renaming, also I've tried to create the form and input programatically, appending them to the body and submitting. Still only the first works.

WORKING VIEW:

```html
<div data-bind="visible: rep.messages().length > 0">
    <div data-bind="foreach: rep.messages">
        <div id="error" data-bind="css: color">
            <div><span data-bind="css: icon"></span></div>
            <div><div data-bind="html: text"></div></div>
            <div>
                <form action="/createPDF.html" method="POST" id="individlonpdf" name="loneandringar" target="_blank">
                    <span onclick=""></span>
                    <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-bind="click: $root.rep.print" id="print-tgl">Skriv ut</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOT WORKING VIEW:

```html
  <div data-bind="visible: rem.newEmployeeMessages().length > 0" id="rem-msg-area">
    <div data-bind="foreach: rem.newEmployeeMessages">
        <div id="error" data-bind="css: color">
            <div><span data-bind="css: icon"></span></div>
            <div><div data-bind="html: text"></div></div>
            <div>
                <form action="/createPDF.html" method="POST" id="ateranstallpdf" name="avanmalan" target="_blank">
                    <span onclick=""></span>
                    <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-bind="click: $root.rem.print" id="print-tgl">Skriv ut</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT 
 Each click event-method is then directed towards the same print-method

Not-working:

```
rem.print = function(){
    mainPdfPrint("ateranstallpdf", data, "avanmalan");
}
```

Working:

```
rep.print = function () {
    mainPdfPrint("individlonpdf", data, "loneandringar");
}
```

The main-method:

```
function mainPdfPrint(formid, datasource, name, stringified) {
    formid = "#" + formid;
    var url = $(formid).attr("action");
    var data = stringified ? datasource : JSON.stringify(datasource);

    var inp = $("<input>", { "value": data, "name": name, "type": "hidden" });
    if ($(formid + " input:hidden").length) {
        $(formid + " input:hidden").remove();
    }
    $(formid).append(inp);
    IK.global.logAnalytics(url);
    document.forms[name].submit();      
}
```

Both working and non-working form-elements are part of the document.forms-collection as they should be.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE

After suggestions here, I've tried a different approach:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="" data-bind="visible:messages().length > 0">
                    <div data-bind="foreach: messages">
                        <div class="col-xs-12" id="error" data-bind="css:color">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 msg-templates">
                                <div class="col-xs-1 no-pad-l info-sign">
                                    <span class="glyphicon" data-bind="css:icon"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 no-pad-l">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 no-pad-lr msg" data-bind="html:text"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad-lr text-right print">
                                    <form class="col-xs-12 no-pad-l" action="/foretag/individkort/skapaPdfAvanmalan.html" method="POST" id="avanmalanpdf" name="avanmalan" target="_blank">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" onclick=""></span>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="avanmalan" data-bind="value:ko.toJSON($root.printableEmployee)" />
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="print-avanmalan" data-bind="click:$root.print">Skriv ut</a>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The problem still persists however, but setting a delay in the print-method triggers the submit-event:

```
   self.print = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.forms.avanmalan.submit();
        }, 600);       
    }
```

Comment: `Form-elements are added in a foreach-loop, in a AJAX-success-event`  - I'm not sure this is your issue but in case it is, - Any events bound to dynamically added elements will not trigger as the binding either needs to be done after the elements are added each time or done through event delegation where the event is bound to the closest static element targeting the dynamic element within. i.e: `('staticElement').on('click', 'dynamicElement', function(){})`

Comment: Yes, I've considered that, but they're all generated in the same way. Still, one works, not the others.

Comment: It's generally always wrong to modify the DOM with jQuery in a knockout application. Your life will become much easier if you stop doing that. The usefulness of jQuery in a knockout application is basically reduced to it's Ajax component and not a lot else (except when you use jQuery-based UI widgets). Everything related to UI modification ought to be done through knockout.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach indicates that you seem to be not really familiar with knockout and try to do too much in a "jQuery" kind of way.

With knockout, your user interface is a function of your view model. All changes in the DOM have to be a result of changes in the underlying data. The task of manually adding input fields with JS code is not part of this approach.

In the following, there is no custom code that modifies the DOM. Everything is done by knockout.

```js
var vm = {
  rep: {
    messages: [
      { color: '', icon: '', text: '<b>Message 1</b> - Text', data: 'some data here 1' },
      { color: '', icon: '', text: '<b>Message 2</b> - Text', data: 'some data here 2' },
      { color: '', icon: '', text: '<b>Message 3</b> - Text', data: 'some data here 3' }
    ]
  },
  catchPost: function () {
    // dummy function to prevent an actual form POST
    console.log("...would send the following data to the server:");
    console.log(ko.toJSON(this.data, null, 2));
    return false;    
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
button.submit {
  border: 0px none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: rep">
  <div data-bind="foreach: messages">
    <div id="error" data-bind="css: color">
      <div><span data-bind="css: icon"></span></div>
      <div><div data-bind="html: text"></div></div>
      <div>
        <form action="/createPDF.html" method="POST" target="_blank" data-bind="submit: $root.catchPost">
          <input type="hidden" name="loneandringar" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(data)">
          <button class="submit" id="print-tgl">Skriv ut</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is no need for *any* custom code in such a simple scenario. Unless you have an explicit dependency on jQuery UI (or a similar library), I suggest you remove jQuery from your application altogether. You can use a dedicated Ajax library if you require it - such as [reqwest](https://github.com/ded/reqwest) - but generally speaking, jQuery is more of a hindrance than a help in knockout applications.

Comment: I guess I could go all-in-Knockout with this scenario, but I have a lot of other views on the same page which use jQuery, and jQuery UI, and it still does not explain the phenomena that one submit works while the others don't. I have used similar approach on my other pages but I haven't encountered any problems with the jQuery/Knockout-combination.

Comment: The phenomena is that you have a typo, I believe, like the other answer suggests.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the question only, not in my live code. I copied the wrong markup into the question. So that is not the issue. Updated the question now.

Comment: I don't say that you *can't* combine jQuery and knockout, I say that you shouldn't. However, jQuery code that modifies the DOM is never necessary in your application code. The only place where DOM-modifying jQuery code should exist is in custom binding handlers. If you have DOM-modifying code in your viewmodel, this can count as a mistake.

Comment: Setting a delay on the submit seems to trigger the submit 

    setTimeout(function () {
                document.forms.avanmalan.submit();
            }, 600);

Comment: I could investigate why your code does not work, but as I said, your approach is wrong and you are trying to solve a problem you would not even have with the proper approach. The sensible thing to do is to change your approach.

Comment: I've now tried your approach, and gone all-in-knockout, but it is not any Knockout/jQuery-issues that's causing the problem, and submit is still not triggered, without the timeout as I've mentioned. So the problem is solved with this workaround, but the actual reason why is not.

Comment: I have a `<submit>` button, not a link with an onclick-Javascript. Did you keep the link? Make a runnable sample that reproduces the error.

Comment: Yes, I tried using a submit-button, that didn't make any difference, the submit was not triggered, so I changed it back to my original link, mostly to keep the original look and because of time issues. I'll try to make a runnable sample if time allows. We have a upcoming release soon, so for now, I'm content that it works. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Now I'm curious what is happening there, be sure to make that sample. The error doesn't really make sense to me yet.

Comment: Sorry! Not enough time yet, due to pending release! It may be related to the page architecture? The views are all default hidden, and expanded on a puff-click. The working views are the top-row view, and the second-row-first-view. The non-working are all on the second-row after the second-row-first-view. Maybe they need the timeout to trigger because of this nesting?

Comment: No, "timeouts to make something work" are unnecessary in knockout (in JS in general). It's a programming/design error somewhere.

Comment: Finally found what caused this problem! When an employee-status has been successfully changed, the non-working views trigger a "pending-refresh"-state, because we need to get new data to populate other areas of the page when the user clicks outside the view. The submit was swallowed by this event-listener.So yes, it was a design/programming-error.

Comment: Nice, congrats for tracking it down. I hope you could get rid of all the goofy `setTimeout()` hacks. :)